# sql join or multiple selects?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables - `Conversations` and `Participants`.

Participants has two columns -  `user_id` and `conversation_id`

Now I want to find all conversations in which two (or more) specific users are participating.

I tried something like this:

```
select conversation_id from participants where id = 123 and id = 456
```

but that obviously didn't work out very well since a row can not have two user_ids at the same time...

Has anyone got any suggestions which way to go from here? Multiple select queries?

Answer (score 3):

```
select conversation_id, count(distinct user_id) 
from participants
where user_id in (u1, u2, u3...)
group by conversation_id
having count(distinct user_id) > 1
```

**Update:** If you your dbms does not support count(distinct  ...) and you are sure that each conversation has each user nonduplicated the you can write the query

```
select conversation_id, count(*) 
from participants
where user_id in (u1, u2, u3...)
group by conversation_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: -1 this will not check for the specific user id's the OP is asking for.

Comment: +1 It will if they are substituted into u1, u2. However, it does require a `group by` clause.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs the `where` was not big deal, you've missed the `group by` :)

Comment: now it will, removed my downvote.  (Strange... what I downvoted looks very different from your original answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select conversation_id 
from participants 
where user_id in (123, 456)
group by conversation_id 
having count(distinct user_id) > 1
```

Comment: The question was for the conversation, not just the conversation id, even though the sql suggested only the conversation id was being looked for.  This is a viable solution though.

Comment: yes works perfectly! thanks a million; will dissect this a bit further later on when i'm home again

Comment: This is the right approach, but it fails the "two (or more) specific users" criterion.  It will work for two, but not for three.

Comment: @CDJorgenson: Only two specific users were supplied in the example. As you say, the same approach should work if more users are specified in the `in` clause, and the `count(distinct user_id) >` condition updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT conversation_id FROM participants WHERE user_id = 123
INTERSECT
SELECT conversation_id FROM participants WHERE user_id = 456
```

Comment: this also looks different from what I downvoted.  How bizarre.  Can you edit your post and I'll remove my downvote; this should work although it may not be very performant. (or it may be, I don't know)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs This was an edit - probably should have made that clearer at the time! Shortly after posting my original answer I ended up going "What the hell were you thinking?" and went back and looked at it again.

Comment: this works beautifully and simply for 2 participants, but you would need to repeat the intersect/select for a 3rd participant

Comment: @AnthonyGrist OK, I didn't see an edit history so I assumed I was losing my mind (safe assumption).  I must have downvoted after your new post but before I refreshed... as it is, I cannot remove my downvote until/ unless you edit your post again.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
select distinct c.*
from conversations as c
inner join participants as p1
on p1.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
where
p1.user_id = 123
and exists (select null from participants as p2 where p2.conversation_id = c.conversation_id 
  and p2.user_id = 456);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to scrap my whole first attempt.  It was the wrong answer.  My new answer is:

```
declare @usersToFind table (userid int)
insert into @usersToFind
                select 11
    union all   select 12
    union all   select 13

select p.convid, count(*) [participantCount]
from
    @participants p
    left join @conversations c
        on p.convid = c.id
where
    p.userid in (select userid from @usersToFind)
group by
    p.convid
    -- identify all conversation columns you care about here, and repeat them in select clause
having
    count(distinct p.userid) >= (select count(*) from @usersToFind)
```

The problem was that it would not accept a list of specific users to search for.  This one will find any conversation where all users (no matter how many you specify) are participants in said conversation.

If interested, here is the sql i used to set up my test:

```
declare @conversations table (id int)
declare @participants table (userid int, convid int)

insert into @conversations values (100)
insert into @conversations values (200)
insert into @conversations values (300)
insert into @conversations values (400)

insert into @participants values (11, 100)
insert into @participants values (12, 100)
insert into @participants values (13, 100)

insert into @participants values (11, 200)
insert into @participants values (12, 200)

insert into @participants values (11, 300)
insert into @participants values (13, 300)

insert into @participants values (12, 400)
insert into @participants values (13, 400)
```

(further edited to remove a column from the select list that wasn't in the group by